# Node Module Paths in Host Application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, module

just like to add a short preface to this question - It may be a true issue of how Node functions, or it may be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of how modules in Node work.

Recently, I've been working on a new project, specifically, a new Node module that requires some configuration via a `.json` file. I've had quite a few issues with this, being tested via linking the module to an Angular 2 (v5) project, and attempting to use the module in a service.

As I have the module set up right now, the configuration is loaded immediately as the module is initialized. It attempts to look for a `config.json` file, and read values from aforementioned file. I have this working, to an extent. I am able to require the file, read the file, and throw an error if the file is not found - but only in the same directory as the module's main file. The issue that I've come across is trying to determine how to find the path to the host project's root path - in this case, the Angular project. For example, say the absolute path to my module's root is `/home/dev/angular2project/src/node_modules/module/`. How can I determine the root path of the host, in this case `/home/dev/angular2project/`? What if the module has been installed globally?

I have attempted to use my weak understanding of the `path` module, paired with various searches of SO, to resolve this issue. I've tried using `path.resolve(__dirname)` to no avail `path.resolve(process.cwd)`. This works well when debugging the module by itself. When attempted to be run from the Angular project, it simply returns `/` as the path, despite the actual root of the Angular project being `home/dev/Desktop/angular2proj`.